# ¿Cómo realizar la revisión "No es una respuesta" en la nueva cola de "Primeras respuestas"?

Tags: discusión, soporte, colas-de-revisión

Recientemente estuve revisando algunas tareas de las nuevas colas de revisión, y me encontré con un pequeño inconveniente.

El problema que veo es, por ejemplo:

Cuando reviso una nueva respuesta que hizo un usuario (Y que no es una respuesta sino debería ser una edición de su pregunta), reporto como "No es una respuesta", una vez reportado tengo las opciones "Se ve bien", "Editar" y "Comparte tus comentarios" disponibles, ésta ultima "Comparte tus comentarios" con solo dos opciones que no se aplican al problema de "no es una respuesta".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora bien como se debe proceder con un problema como el que planteo en el caso de "Primeras respuestas".

Lo que hice para testear un poco fue:

- Reportar "No es una respuesta"
- Dejar un comentario para aclarar que el usuario debe editar su pregunta en lugar de una respuesta
- Luego marqué la opción de "Comparte tus comentarios"

Pero los comentarios que veo no aplican para este problema y **se me obliga marcar una opción entre ("Se ve bien", "Editar" y "Comparte tus comentarios") para continuar**, entonces ¿Debería simplemente omitir la revisión?.

Comment: LO que no entiendo es la diferencia entre "primeras publicaciones" y "primeras preguntas"

Comment: @Japv, bueno anteriormente era "Primeras publicaciones", pero ahora esa quedó obsoleta y actualmente es "Primeras preguntas" y "Primeras respuestas".

Comment: La diferencia es simplemente que "Primeras publicaciones" abarcaban tanto preguntas como respuestas y ahora están separadas en dos colas.

Comment: Y porque no quitan entonces primeras publicaciones, ya que quedo dividida en dos colas

Comment: Eso me ha ocurrido que me ha dejado pensando qué hacer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Las nuevas colas de revisión han sido anunciadas en el sitio de SE en [este post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369013/review-queue-workflows-final-release).

Creo que por el momento los comentarios no están traducidos (supongo que algunos si). Lo que puedes hacer es colaborar con la traducción en [traducir.win](https://es.traducir.win/) creado por @g3rv4 para que todas las personas colaboren con la traducción.

En cuanto a no poder eliminar el comentario es por que el usuario comunidad es el autor del comentario y no tu como lo era en otras colas de revisión.

En [esta publicación](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369036/1045460) se habla de que no hay una forma correcta de manejar o elegir el comentario en la cola de primeras respuestas.

Comment: Otra cosa que me acabo de dar cuenta es que también puedo reportar una "Primera pregunta" y luego darle al botón *se ve bien* XD algo extraño creo.

Comment: Esto ultimo tambien se dijo en el post de meta SE, tambien puedes mirar [esta publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/479432/no-puedo-acceder-a-un-campo-de-la-respuesta-quiero-acceder-al-campo-estado-para#comment853515_479432) y [la mía](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369047/1045460)

Comment: @Israel-ICM jeje, perdón era [esta publicación](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369036/1045460)

Comment: Si tienes razón @Christian, no había leído esa respuesta. ;)